# tumblr infinite scroll has an error

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, imagesloaded

I don't really know how to explain, so you can see the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZi4z.jpg). The posts basically crowd each other and overlap each other.
I'm using a javascript code for the infinite scroll:

```
{block:IndexPage}
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/H8Glm663z/masonry.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/qNulm663d/infinite.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
$('#posts').masonry(),
$('.masonryWrap').infinitescroll({
navSelector : "div.navigation",
// selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : ".navigation a#next",
// selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : ".entry",
// selector for all items you'll retrieve
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 10000,
loadingImg : "http://static.tumblr.com/bcpenwm/o5Nmy3k0o/florels.gif",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function() { $('#posts').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
);
});
</script>
{/block:IndexPage}


<div class="navigation">{block:Pagination}
{block:NextPage}
<span id="page_nav"><span onclick='return false;'>
<a style="float:right;opacity:0;" href="{NextPage}" id="next"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
{block:PreviousPage}
<a style="float:right;opacity:0;" href="{PreviousPage}"></a>
</span></span>
{/block:PreviousPage}
{/block:Pagination}</div>
```

From what I've noticed it sometimes work, it sometimes doesnt, I think it's depending on how do the posts arrange themselves or I don't know. You can access the page [here](https://derovada.tumblr.com/tagged/heythere). It could work for your resolution though.
I believe it is also connected to the css command `#maino {verflow:hidden/visible/scroll}` If I select scroll I get 2 scroll bars so that's not ok

Comment: The issues is caused by calling `$('#posts').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) });` before the images have fully downloaded. 

To resolve this use http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: @mikedidthis hey man, I don't really know javascript that well, how do I use that?